# Error Handling issue with cin.fail()

Tags: c++, error-handling, char, int, cin

If I input a character 's' for instance, why does this still go into an infinite loop prompting me for ""How many people are playing? (1-5): "?

```
int getnumplayers(){
    int num_players =0;
    while(true){
        cout<<"How many people are playing? (1-5): ";
        //cin.ignore();
        cin>>num_players;

        if(cin.fail()){
            cout<<"hello";
        }

        else if((num_players < 6 && num_players > 0)){
            break;  
        }
    }
    return num_players;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

once cin.fail() is set, you need to clear it with cin.clear() before cin is willing to read again.  So, it's skipping over your requests for reads because the stream is not "good".

I think you want the line

```
cin.clear(cin.rdstate() & ~ios_base::failbit);
cin.ignore();
```

in your if(cin.fail()) block.